# python: split a line

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a log file where every line follows this format :

systemMonitor: [YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS,###] [STATUS] node-id: some error some description of error: more info about it, a lot of white spaces

so we have 4 parts that are all ways the same: systemMonitor , the date, and the status (error, info, success etc...) node ID 
after that, we get the error it self which can differ from one error to another

I want to parse the line so I'll get a dictionary where:

```
main: systemMonitor,
date: the date,
status: the status,
error_msg: the error msg,
```

I have tried splitting it by white spaces, did not work.
currently, I am hard coding it: at line[14] we get the systemMonitor part at another index I get the date and etc... .

is there a better way of achieving it?

Example lines :

SystemMonitor: [2017-08-07 10:05:00,333] [ERROR] 12432: missing port number 302
SystemMonitor: [2017-08-07 10:05:00,333] [ERROR] 13332: cant reach host

Comment: Regular expressions are the way to go (re module). What do you mean by "at line[14] we get the systemMonitor part at another index"?

Comment: if we substring the line from index 0 to that index we get the string "systemMonitor:"

Comment: could you post your original input, not just your desired output?

Comment: Firstly, think how a human recognize the fields, then write your code and search the suitable function

Answer (score 1):

Try to use regular expressions. Here is an example, which can (and should) be improved, but it will get you started:

```
import re
m=re.match(r"systemMonitor: \[(?P<date>.+)\] \[(?P<status>\w+)\] (?P<node_id>\d+): (?P<error>.*)\s*", line)
```

Then you can get the values with `m.group("date")`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

would this be a useful solution? Use what you have!

```
lne='SystemMonitor:[2017-08-07 10:05:00,333] [ERROR] 12432: missing portnumber 302'

date = lne[15:25] # I really see no problem in hard coding here
status = lne.split('[')[-1].split(']')[0] 
error_msg = lne.split(':')[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import re
output = ["SystemMonitor: [2017-08-07 10:05:00,333] [ERROR] 12432: missing port number 302",  "SystemMonitor: [2017-08-07 10:05:00,333] [ERROR] 13332: cant reach host"]

headers = ["main", "date", "status", "error_msg"]

new_data = [re.split("\s(?=\[)", i) for i in output]

new_data = [i[:-1]+i[-1].split(":") for i in new_data]

final_error_messages = [{a:b for a, b in zip(headers, i)} for i in new_data]
```

The output contains a list of dictionaries with the data that you wanted:

```
[{'date': '[2017-08-07 10:05:00,333]', 'status': '[ERROR] 12432', 'main': 'SystemMonitor:', 'error_msg': ' missing port number 302'}, {'date': '[2017-08-07 10:05:00,333]', 'status': '[ERROR] 13332', 'main': 'SystemMonitor:', 'error_msg': ' cant reach host'}]
```